# How to inherit react component props in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I come to react (as well as react-native) with typescript, of course, I'm a beginner, so soon my company assigns me to support a javascript project, and I have javascript questions

In typescript, if we want to use props, I think the best, also cool way to do that is using `Interface`, it also let me have `IntelliSense code` in vs code

```
export interface FooI {
  some: string;
  propsA: string;
  here: number;
}
```

And use that in component:

```
export default function Bar(props: FooI) {
  const {some, propsA, here} = props;
}
```

And we also can inherit react component( in this case is react-native), so if I want the component will be a button, so I add

```
export interface FooI extends ButtonProps {
  some: string;
  propsA: string;
  here: number;
}
```

As I know we don't have that in javascript, so what is similar to the interface in javascript so I can create a custom component like above and vs code will recognize that and show an auto-complete pop-up?

Comment: you dont - you just go for it 

Comment: ES6 classes comes to mind.

Comment: Oh no, so these next day will be nighmare :((( , no intellisense code, no interface, no complier warning

Comment: You just worked out why typescript was invented. Javascript is the wild west, typescript is the sheriff!

Comment: Confirm that @Jamiec , it so terrible, but i have to finish this 7 years old proj :(